# How to use a Lexical Decorator Node without React?

Tags: lexicaljs

I'm trying to add a Node to Lexical that can display both an Image and some (static) text - it's not meant to be editable through the editor.

From what I can tell a Decorator Node is the way to go to display arbitrary DOM elements, however unfortunately there is no information what the `decorate` method should return when not using react.

What does the method have to return without react?

Answer (score 0):

The Decorator Node is used for outputting components from the library by using the decorate() build-in method.
If you don't want to use it with react, you do not need to use Decorator Node. ElementNode and TextNode are enough to implemented your ImageNode